# React JS onDragCapture vs onDrag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In React js to every drag event there is a corresponding event with "capture"  prefix
***onDragEnter vs onDragEnterCapture, onDragLeave vs onDragLeaveCapture*** and so on.
Could any one tell difference between those and when to use which? They both repond to similar events.

Comment: @RameshRajendran i am drying to create something with drag drop and when i  see the events available for drag to every drag event  i get a corresponding event with   Capture prefix...

Comment: @RameshRajendran like both onDragEnter and onDragEnterCapture are available

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically Bubbling and Capturing are two ways of event propagation.

**Bubbling** :
When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.
Let’s say we have 3 nested elements `form> div> p` with a handler on each of them:

A click on the inner `<p>` first runs onclick:

1. On that `<p>`.
2. Then on the outer `<div>`.
3. Then on the outer `<form>`.
4. And so on upwards till the document object.

**Capturing** : The event is first captured by the outermost element and propagated to the inner elements:

So in the same example when you click the outer element `<form>` it runs on :

1. on that `<form>`
2. then the inner `<div>`
3. then `<p>`

While using react, to register an event handler for the capture phase, append Capture to the event name; for example, instead of using onClick, you would use onClickCapture to handle the click event in the capture phase.

The same goes for the other events.

Source [[1]](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)  [[2]](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)